# How can I make "inherited" appear at the end of my procedure instead of beginning?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, virtual-functions

First of all, I doubt this is even possible, but if it is, I'd love to know how. I recall seeing this behavior before, but it could be explicitly implemented in the IDE.

I have a base form which I then inherit into various other forms. In the base form, I have a number of virtual methods which are to be overridden and implemented by the inherited forms.

There are certain virtual methods which expect `inherited` to be called at the *end* of the procedure. However, by default, it gets automatically inserted at the *beginning*. This tends to cause confusion, specifically forgetting to call it at the end instead of the beginning.

How could I force `inherited` to get inserted at the *end* instead of the *beginning*, like below, if at all possible?

```
procedure TMyForm.DoStuff;
begin

  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to sometimes do it one way and sometimes another, which is what I think you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change this behaviour of the IDE.

The IDE knows that certain methods, e.g. overridden destructors, expect the `inherited` statement to appear at the end of the method body. For such methods, the IDE does indeed place the call to `inherited` at the end of the method body when performing class completion. But there is no mechanism for you to tell the IDE that other methods, about which it knows nothing, are to be treated that way.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do know methods other than destructors showing this behaviour?

Comment: @UliGerhardt I don't. One might have expected overridden `BeforeDestruction` to behave the same way, but it doesn't. Similarly one might imagine that overridden `OnDestroy` event handlers might behave this way, but they don't. My guess is that overridden destructors are the sole example.

Answer (score 3):

To add to David's answer, if you need to enforce this order of operations the best way to do it is by changing the design.  Decoupling the operations which need to happen afterwards can be done something like this :

```
type
  TMyBase = class
    protected
      DoBeforeSomething : procedure; virtual; abstract;
    public
      DoSomething : procedure;
  end;

  TMyCustom = class(TMyBase)
    protected
      DoBeforeSomething : procedure; override;
  end;

procedure TMyBase.DoSomething;
begin
  DoBeforeSomething;
  // Do common things now...
end;

procedure TMyCustom.DoBeforeSomething;
begin
  inherited;
  // some custom things...
end;
```

Here the consumer would always call the `DoSomething` method to perform whatever operation is intended but the inheriting class would override `DoBeforeSomething`, which is called first in `DoSomething` before whatever other operations need to be done.

This way the descendent class doesn't have to worry about overriding `DoSomething` itself and calling `inherited` in the "wrong" place, the design of the class takes care of getting the operations in the correct order.

Comment: Doesn't scale to multiple levels of inheritance and doesn't really address the Q

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, it doesn't scale in the way you're implying but I don't think the problem in the question required that specific type of behaviour.  And while it doesn't directly address the question it *does* provide a useful solution to the problem faced in the question.